# Google Sheets + Apps Script: create datalist only if column contain a specific word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi just wondering if someone could help me modify this code (Thanks Tanaike) so it would search in Column 'G' a specific word then create a datalist from row that match the word in the variable specWord

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label for="test">test</label>
          <input type="text" id="test1" class="form-control" list="test" name="test" 
           onchange="test4()">
          <datalist id="test"  >
            <?
            var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("info");
            var specWord = "Apple"; /// Specific Word to look for
            var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
            var myRange = sheet.getRange("E2:G"+lastRow);
            var data    = myRange.getValues();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
            <option value="<?!= data[i] ?>">
            <? } ?>
          </datalist>
```

so the datalist would be created from the 3 item matching "Apple" in column 'G'

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use the rows filtered with the value of `specWord` in the column "G", how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = myRange.getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var data = myRange.getValues().filter(([,,g]) => g == specWord);
```

#### Note:

- If above modification occurs an error, please modify it to `var data = myRange.getValues().filter(function([,,g]) {return g == specWord});`

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Hi Tanaike I'm trying to replace the "Apple" with value from an Element by id
var specWord = "Apple"; /// Specific Word to look for with
var specWord = document.getElementById('item1').value;
but I cant seem to get it working I always get this error   
ReferenceError: specWord is not defined (line 660) 
any suggestion

Comment: @Yvan L About your new issue, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand your new issue. I apologize for my poor English skill. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to try to understand about your new issue. And also, it will help users think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?